# picamera2 how to capture multiple images (3) with different exposure speed, as fast as possible?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I switched from the 1. gen Raspberry Pi to the Raspberry Pi 4. Now I want to migrate my picamera(1) project to picamera2. But I cant find a way to capture 3 images in a row, each with a different exposure speed.
code with picamera(1):

```
camera.shutter_speed = 1000
camera.capture('image-1.jpg', use_video_port=False)

camera.shutter_speed = 7000
camera.capture('image-2.jpg', use_video_port=False)

camera.shutter_speed = 13000
camera.capture('image-3.jpg', use_video_port=False)
```

The execution took a bit less than 2 seconds. My hope was, that with the new Pi it would took much less time to capture the 3 images. Is there a way to make this with picamera2?

I tried to set the ExposureTime like:

```
picam2.controls.ExposureTime = 1000
picam2.capture_file('image-1.jpeg')

picam2.controls.ExposureTime = 7000
picam2.capture_file('image-2.jpeg')

picam2.controls.ExposureTime = 13000
picam2.capture_file('image-3.jpeg')"
```

It seems, that I cant change the exposure_time after the camera.start() method.

Comment: Why do you expect that this takes much less than 2 seconds?

Comment: Because I thought, that the Pi 4 is much more powerful in processing speed. But if it doesn't get much faster, it doesn't really matter in the first place..

Comment: What is the sum of the exposure times?

Comment: in picamera(1) the sum is 21.000 microseconds I dont know if the exposure times in picamera2 is set in microseconds too. But according to the documentation, it should also be set in microseconds.

Comment: I think I wasn't precise enough in the question. My problem is that I can't set the exposure time with picamer2. Unfortunately, all three images have the same exposure time.

Comment: I seem to recall you need to actually **disable** auto-exposure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that every time you change the ExposureTime it takes a few frames for the new setting to settle. If you capture the image immediately after changing the exposureTime, it will be captured with the previous setting.
You either have to insert a delay between the setting and the capture or stop and start the camera system each time (which guarantees that the new setting is applied on the first frame).
See official Picamera2 documentation https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/picamera2-manual.pdf, chapter 5.1.1.
Example: https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/blob/main/examples/opencv_mertens_merge.py

Answer (score 0):

You need to sleep (`time.sleep(0.1)` works for me) between frames to allow for config propagation, seems that picamera2 keeps requesting images from sensor and hands to you the latest when you ask, but your request didn't trigger a poll from sensor. This would explain why your setting is not present in the frame you get.
Also, why do you want 3 different exposures and not an optimal exposure?
I figured (a few minutes ago) that the best exposure is that which maximizes the difference between darkest and brightest pixels. coded this (I'm publishing it in a gist soon) and the result is beautiful.

```py
def guessExposure():
    image = picam2.capture_array("main")
    idxs = list(zip(np.random.randint(image.shape[0], size=100), np.random.randint(image.shape[1], size=100)))
    lightAmplitudes = []

    minExposure = 40  # From CameraModes `modes = picam2.sensor_modes`
    maxExposure = 298143
    step = 50000  # about 5 frames
    bestExposures = np.array([[]])
    initialWaitDone = False
    previousExposures = np.array([[-1, -1, -1]])
    for i in range(4):
        for exposure in range(minExposure, maxExposure, step):
            with picam2.controls as ctl:
                ctl.ExposureTime = exposure

            goodImage = False
            while not goodImage:
                time.sleep(0.1 if initialWaitDone else 1)
                initialWaitDone = True
                # discard buffered.
                image = picam2.capture_array("main")
                previousExposure = np.where(previousExposures[:, 1] == exposure)
                image = picam2.capture_array("main")
                light = np.zeros(100)
                lightIdx = 0
                for row, col in idxs:
                    light[lightIdx] = np.mean(image[row][col])
                    lightIdx += 1
                amplitude = max(light) - min(light)
                avg = np.mean(light)
                if previousExposure[0].size > 0:
                    # Assumes 1st shot at current exposure was good.
                    goodImage = previousExposures[previousExposure[0][0]][0] - amplitude < 50
                else:
                    goodImage = True
                if goodImage:
                    lightAmplitudes.append(np.array([amplitude, exposure , avg]))
                else:
                    print(f"discarding bad image.", amplitude, exposure , avg)

            previousExposures = np.vstack((previousExposures, lightAmplitudes[-1:]))

        pp.pprint(lightAmplitudes)
        maxLightAmplitudeIndex = np.argmax(lightAmplitudes, axis=0)[0]
        print(maxLightAmplitudeIndex)
        bestExposures = np.array([lightAmplitudes[maxLightAmplitudeIndex]])
        for lightAmplitude, exposure, lightAvg in lightAmplitudes:
            if (lightAmplitudes[maxLightAmplitudeIndex][0] - lightAmplitude <= 10
                    and exposure != lightAmplitudes[maxLightAmplitudeIndex][1]):
                bestExposures = np.vstack((bestExposures, np.array([lightAmplitude, exposure, lightAvg])))

        pp.pprint(bestExposures)
        minExposure = int(min(bestExposures[:, 1]))
        maxExposure = int(max(bestExposures[:, 1]))
        if maxExposure == minExposure:
            maxExposure = minExposure + step // 2
            minExposure = minExposure - step // 2 if minExposure > step // 2 else minExposure

        step = 1 + (maxExposure - minExposure) // 5
        lightAmplitudes = []

    sortedByLightAvg = np.argsort(bestExposures[:, 2])
    medianIndex = sortedByLightAvg[len(sortedByLightAvg) // 2]
    # exposure value for middle lightAvg in set of biggest amplitude.
    bestExposure = int(bestExposures[medianIndex][1])
    print(f"BEst exposure {bestExposure}")
    return bestExposure
```

> [gist](https://gist.github.com/juanmf/b2b4c87469c1f2be7d757fe4bcd741a9)
>
> Edited to fix (discard) random bad pics

In case several exposures are optimal, pick mean + standard deviation. (for my needs a little brighter with no loss is best). thus

`return int(np.average(bestExposures) + np.std(bestExposures))`

It's dark here, tried with lights off and all lights on, image looks great.

Left program running switched on-off some lights:

[image: bright]

> bright

[image: dark]

> dark

[image: superDark]

> super dark.

[image: sunlight]

> Updated with next day sunlight. (seems I need to start with lower values as the picked exposure was 2nd value.)

Exposure was updated automatically.